# Semantic layout with Bootstrap 3 in SASS - include or extend

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, performance, sass

I have read quite a few articles about the include vs extend in SASS but I still haven't found a definite "best practices" technique for achieving something very simple yet essential to any layout - the naming of the grid DIVs.

In my case, I want to have a section with content in the footer and its class would be `footer-section` and it will be visible only on desktop and hide in mobile views for the lack of real estate there. In general it should behave like `.col-md-4` `.hidden-sm` and `hidden-xs` using the Bootstrap 3 convention.

What would be the best recommended way of achieving that semantic layout with SASS. Should be it be something like:

```
.footer-section {
    @extend .col-md-4;
    @extend .hidden-sm;
    @extend .hidden-xs;
}
```

Or `include` will serve that concept more efficient in terms of css size and performance?

Comment: I'd personally use include just because of being used to bourbon and neat.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744625/sass-and-bootstrap-mixins-vs-extends